# How to compare Time value in table with Current Time in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, time

I have a table named `TimeList`:

```
|    Slot    |
==============
|    10:00   |
|    11:00   |
|    12:00   |
|    13:00   | and so on
```

That saves the Times in Varchar(5)

The desired result should be showing the rows with time that is more than the current time, for example if the current time is 11:12 A.M. the result should return:

```
|    Slot    |
==============
|    12:00   |
|    13:00   |
```

I tried to Convert the two values into time and comparing them with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TimeList
WHERE Convert(Time, Slot) > Convert(Time, GETDATE())
```

But it didn't work saying that `Time` is not a recognizable format in SQL

Is there anyway I could compare the two time slots?

Comment: What sql server you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the answers, fortunately I found the answer to my question inspired by your answers.

The solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TimeList
WHERE Slot > CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(), 108)
```

Where it seems that 108 is the format for time saved as char/varchar in which Slot was categorized as too

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the version of SQL Server you're running, I think. There is a CAST(.. as time) in 2012 or later, but I think that's a fairly new development. So... to compare the current date/time with the Timelist where the times are converted to "time, if it were today," something like this should work :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TimeList
WHERE Convert(Datetime, FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'd') + ' ' + Slot) > GETDATE()
```

Conversely, if you want to compare the times to the current time, as text:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TimeList
WHERE Slot > FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'hh\:mm')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This.....

```
SELECT *
FROM    TimeList
WHERE Slot > CONVERT(time,GETDATE())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.